# Return new line from file each time function is called

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for a piece of code which does the following

- Runs as an individual function
- Reads a file line by line
- Each time the function is called it returns the next line of the file. Not a random line, it needs to work down one line at a time.

Pseudo code:

```
file = readingInFile()
i = i++
for line[i] in file:
    return line
```

Comment: you are looking for `yield`

Comment: What's wrong with using the built-in `next` function on the file object? BTW, you shouldn't use `file` as a variable name in Python 2 because that shadows the built-in `file` type.

Comment: What is not trivial in this question is how you handle the opening and closing of file, so I don't see why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code which I used in the end.

```
def emailToTry():  # Generate a new email from a file
    with open('leakedEmails.txt') as f:  # Using a file of leaked email address, can also use a brute forcer.
        for line in f:
            yield line  # Returns the next line each time it is called
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `yield` but it's what you want i think

```
def read_file(file_name):
    f = (open(file_name, "r")).read().splitlines()
    for line in f:
        yield line
    f.close()

file_opened = read_file("test.txt")

for line in file_opened:
    print(line)
```